# Failed to Complete action : create_index in Elasticsearch AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to insert multiple indices in Elasticsearch using single document API. I have around 9000 multiple indices. And each index has multiple documents.

single document API: `es.index(index=myObject._id, doc_type=doc_name, body=records,request_timeout=40)`

The process starts fine but interestingly enough after inserting 499 random indices (having multiple documents), I receive an error during inserting action.

The error is:

```
RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[9de9df3c092bfd8ae79870249a31cf28][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:admin/create]').
```

I am running Elasticsearch on AWS and I am using Python Elasticsearch Client

Edited:

I did a small experiment.

```
for index_ in range(0,1000,1):
    wb_record=dict()
    wb_record['md']=0
    es.index(index=str(index_), doc_type='wellbore_data', body=wb_record,request_timeout=100)
```

And still I got the same error

```
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[72a30a0a1c8b23082c09610fd1bc32a8][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:admin/create]')
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this error?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify whether your running ES on AWS EC2 or the AWS ES managed service?

Comment: this is AWS Elastic Search Service (managed)

Comment: @Val Hi Val, I am running on AWS ES managed services.

Comment: Are you [streaming your ES logs](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/big-data/viewing-amazon-elasticsearch-service-error-logs/) to Cloudwatch by any chance?

Comment: yes, I am streaming to Cloudwatch

Comment: Ok, good, then there must be more info in the ES server logs are for this error, can you check?

Comment: @Val - Hi, but I don't see any log in Cloudwatch related to the above error.

Comment: Try after setting request timeout to a large number

Comment: @AlwaysSunny thanks for the response. I just now tried with 100. but the same error.

Comment: @Val - did a small experiment. Added in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first [create an index](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.13.2/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create) and then only you can upload the documents to the index.
Use the following line of code to create an index:

```
es.indices.create(INDEX_NAME, request_timeout=100)
```